# Start router after fetching data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, asynchronous, marionette

I have a Backbone.Marionette app with a module that fetches a model data via socket.io when initializing. I start the router with this:

```
App.on('initialize:after', function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

The problem is that the router starts before the data is fetched, and so my view doesn't render.

What should I do for my view to display after the model is fetched on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't seem to be related to the router. The router simply parses the URL to call the proper actions. If your view doesn't render, it means your application isn't calling the controller actions properly.

You should wait for the data within the view (regardless of router status). One convenient way to do so is by using jQuery deferreds. You can reads about them in some of my blog posts:

- http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/
- http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/02/rendering-a-view-after-multiple-async-functions-return-using-promises/

In addition, you can see one use here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/show/show_controller.js This code is taken from my [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction), and uses a deferred/promise to display a loading view while data is being "fetched".

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

from here and put it in the success callback of fetch.

You can always initialise the router at start but actually `history.start()` does the redirection.

**Update**

Detecting success of multiple fetches:

```
//Declare an array 
App.modules = [];

//When you initialise each module, push it to array
App.modules.push(this.id);

//Declare a counter for modules 
App.moduleCounter = 0;

var startHistory = function() {
     App.moduleCounter++;        

     if(App.modules.length === App.moduleCounter) {
           Backbone.history.start();
      }    
 } 

//Call this function on each success 
 startHistory();
```

Comment: The problem is that I have several modules that fetch different data. I can't put `Backbone.history.start()` in each success callback, I'd like to keep it at the app level

Comment: It all really depends how your app is structured. You can detect each fetch success and then call it.

Comment: Ok, and how can I detect the fetch success of each module in my application?

Comment: Check updated answer - You need to do something along these lines